# Laravel scope method check in other table?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have 3 models, Customer, Service and ServiceElement

My scope in model Customer:

```
public function scopeServicesExternal($query, $customer_id, $service_id){
        return $query->where('customer_id', $customer_id)->where('service_id', $service_id);
}
```

This scope gives me all results for a service, this is ok. but it is possible to extend it to get only elements which field agent is not empty in model ServiceElement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the server has a relationship defined to the service element, then you can do:

```
->whereHas('serviceElement', function($query) {
    return $query->where('field_agent', '!=', '');
});
```

Which will return only models that have a record for `serviceElement` and where the `field_agent` column is not empty.

Replace `serviceElement` with however you defined the relationship in your model file.

Answer (score 0):

You will not need pass customer_id and service_id as argument if you use Eloquent relationships.